# Generate a boolean representation of binned numbers in R

Tags: r

Given a sequence of integers between 1 and 10 000, I would like to generate a boolean vector representation of 20 bins (spaced by 500 each). Is there a more efficient solution than the one below? The code is being applied to some 30 million rows.

```
> x <- cumsum(c(1038, 1033, 1078, 1070, 1041, 1088, 1086, 1026))
> as.integer(1:20 %in% .bincode(x, seq(0,10000, by = 500))  )
 [1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: In your example you have one result vector of length 20. Don't you want a binary vector for each record in x? E.g. a 8 by 20 matrix in this case?

Comment: Binary here refers to a numerical representation of a Boolean as (1,0). Perhaps using binary is confusing in this context, I changed the title and the question. The goal is to have a Boolean representation of weather a bin is populated in a vector x.

Comment: I thought that using something like `unique` on the output of `.bincode` would help, but the time is almost exactly the same as your solution. But in both cases the runtime is below 1s, so, unless you are planning to do this very often, it seems that there is little room for improvement.